# Can't acces to the height of a div in an Iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

here is my problem:
the size of my iFrame must vary according to the size of a div in it and when I try to get the size of this div everything I try returns 0

```html
var childiFrame = document.getElementById("myDiv");
                        console.log(childiFrame,"here is my iframe");
                        var innerDoc = childiFrame.contentWindow.document; 
                        console.log(innerDoc,"here is the innerDoc where i have to find my div");
                        mdDiv =innerDoc.getElementById("md");
                        console.log(mdDiv,"here is my div !");// and i can see the clientHeight =245
                        var divHeight = mdDiv.clientHeight; // or offsetHeight or scrollHeight
                        console.log(divHeight,"the div height always equals 0 !");
```

I haven't seen anyone talk about this problem, so if anyone has any ideas, I'll take it!

Answer (score 2):

Please put this script in the parent page -

```js
<script> 
window.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
 var data = e.data.split('-'),
  scroll_height = data[0],
  iframe_id = data[1];
 if(iframe_id == 'iframe1')
  document.getElementById('iframe-container-1').style.height = scroll_height + 'px'; } , false);
</script>
```

Put this script in iframe

```js
<script>
        setInterval(function () {
        window.top.postMessage(document.body.scrollHeight + '-' + 'iframe1', "*");
        }, 500);
</script>
```

Comment: That's awesome!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to wait for iframe to fully load first using the `onload` event, then try to access the `mdDiv` attributes like:

```
var childiFrame = document.getElementById("myDiv");
console.log(childiFrame, "here is my iframe");
childiFrame.onload = function() {
  console.log('my iframe is loaded');

  var innerDoc = childiFrame.contentDocument ? childiFrame.contentDocument : childiFrame.contentWindow.document;
  console.log(innerDoc, "here is the innerDoc where i have to find my div");

  mdDiv = innerDoc.getElementById("md");
  console.log(mdDiv, "here is my div !");

  var divHeight = mdDiv.clientHeight; // or offsetHeight or scrollHeight
  console.log(divHeight);
};
```

Comment: thx ! i waited for the console.log and it show the good height :)

Comment: Please consider marking the answer as [accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/205255) to help future users too. Thanks!